# Unable to create flutter project with name "myFirstApp"

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I installed everything that needed in flutter but I'm unable to create a project.

Here's the error message:
[image: Error Message]

Comment: you cannot have camel case names

Answer (score 3):

Project name must not contain capital letters. It should be `[a-z0-9_]`.
change like this

```
flutter create my_first_app
```

For more [info](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec#name)

Answer (score 1):

**The name should be all lowercase, with underscores to separate words(my_first_app). Use only basic Latin letters and Arabic digits: [a-z0-9_]. Also, make sure the name is a valid Dart identifier—that it doesn’t start with digits and isn’t a reserved word.**